# Tried using Katoolin without knowing what it did, Ubuntu is broken now

Tags: dual-boot, windows, kali, katoolin

Some background info

- I'm running a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04
- I did something stupid like this because I've used Windows my whole life so I didn't realize what apt can do if I'm not careful (I guess sudo is needed for a reason)
- No, I did not read the documentation, yes it wasn't a good idea, no I will not do it again.
- Why I would want to use Kali is because I was asked by a teacher to install Kali, so I thought about just using Katoolin to install Kali tools on Ubuntu

What happened:

1. I ran Katoolin 3 and told it to install everything
2. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. It began to throw a bunch of errors, so I used `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, then used `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again
4. Repeated this process until I got tired of the errors, so I tried restarting my laptop, only to be greeted with "Kali GNU/Linux" instead of the usual "Ubuntu" on the Grub menu
5. After selecting "Kali GNU/Linux", it showed the following messages:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
[FAILED] Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
[FAILED] Failed to start Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
```

6. I selected the Ubuntu recovery option and told it to resume normally, this time it didn't show anything at all, just a blinking white rectangle. Pressing the power button shows a log though.

What I need help with:

- All I want is to at least get my Ubuntu partition working, I have no important data there so I'm okay with doing a reset, but I'm not sure how to do that while making sure my Windows install stays safe. I've seen some threads explaining it but I'm not sure if the presence of Katoolin will mess things up.

If there is any other information you need, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I can't even get to the terminal. Thanks for the help though

Comment: The fastest and convenient option is to reinstall the system since you now have [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

Comment: Ah alright, I was holding off on doing it for a bit but I guess it's my best option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have important data, the easiest way to fix the issue is to reinstall Ubuntu in the same partition you had Ubuntu installed.

When Ubuntu asks for where to install Ubuntu during partitioning (See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/124466) for details), choose "something else", and set the mount point of the partition where Ubuntu was installed as `/` (root), so that the installer will again install it there.
The installer should automatically detect the Windows 10, and it would automatically configure the dual boot.